# How the pdf of this equation calculated?

Tags: probability

I am not getting it ,how this pdf is obtained.I was given a cdf and they took its derivative to obtain the pdf but how this cos(tk) remain inside as well as outside.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're taking the derivative with respect to $x$, so the $|\cos(t_k)|$ is just a constant. It comes outside and stays inside because of the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule). Presumably, you are given somewhere that the density function $f_\zeta(z) \equiv 1/2$ over some range, which gives you the last line.